# Listening for a conversation timeout with Weld

Tags: jboss, jboss-weld

I know it is possible with seam as there is an event that gets fired when a conversation times out. Is there a work around for Weld so that I can listen for a conversation timing out?

Answer (score 0):

Weld is a core of Seam 3. So there should be no problem since you already know how to do it in Seam.